# Paths/curves are not being converted to meshes

Tags: mesh

I tried all the possible, searched, etc. but can't come to a solution to this seemingly stupid problem.
My paths look correct.
I simplified: I splitted the different paths into their basic shapes, so I'll produce the booleans later.
Yet, Blender won't give me solids in any way.
I started with the simpler one: the rounded rectangle. No way.
Here is the file: https://mega.nz/file/6bZjwArB#zXXbEvNV9gBnPhT6NMprAplFdI5mn66JxdvxuhyKegc

The various paths.
[image: The various paths.]

Initially at the selected vertex the path was open. I thought that that was the problem, so I merged the vertices and it should be ok now, but it still doesn't work.
[image: Initially at the selected vertex the path was open. I thought that that was the problem, so I merged the vertices and it should be ok now, but it still doesn't work.]

This is what happens with the modifier Solidify: the path is just duplicated. No solidification occur. No mesh is generated.
[image]

This is what happens with the Skin modifier: the path is solidified. But that's not what I want. I want the rounded rectangle to become a face, and then to extrude it.
[image]

Comment: Please provide screenshots, use blend-exchange.com, and change the question to be more precise.

Comment: I don't know how to be more precise. Blender simply is not converting paths into meshes, there is nothing else to say, and the description expands on this. Screenshots won't change a thing, since I could only provide... screenshots of the paths I am trying to convert: paths in the viewport. I can't understand why so many people here like to keep this stance of nonsensical bureaucratic pickiness really.

Comment: it’s not bureaucracy, it’s the fact that that file provider system is completely foreign, and I don’t know what’s on it. Additionally, I don’t know why you bring up blender “not giving you solids“ since converting a curve to mesh should never produce solids and is not expected to. I was asking for screenshots just so I could understand you, not because I’m trying to follow “protocol.”

Comment: Fair enough that screenshots would probably not help the problem, though.

Comment: I will say that the grammar of your question was quite confusing, and I had to read it twice before I understood fully what you meant.

Comment: @PolyMad the " *nonsensical bureaucratic pickiness* " is probably a good sign that the information you provided is insufficient. Showing resistance towards requests for more info is a good way to ensure people trying to help out of their free time will avoid doing so in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curves are converting to meshes just fine.. it's just that the meshes don't have faces.

- Switch the curves to 2D in their Data tab > Geometry panel
- Set their 'Fill' method to 'Both'
- In Edit mode, with all splines in each curve selected, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> 'Toggle Cyclic'. (The curves are all broken at the moment.. you can't fill a line)

Now, when you convert, the meshes will have faces. They will be horribly triangulated, so I would recommend selecting all edges, and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* to clean up.

Now your meshes will be ready for further manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to work first in your svg file to fill the region you want to extrude with a solid color.

Then in Layout tab when you will convert the region to mesh you will have already the faces where the region is filled.
[image]

In the Modelling tab you can now extruede (E) and then (X) `Limited dissolve`. To get a clean mesh.
[image]